# How to turn off Sticky Edges in Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: gnome

When I used Unity, I remember seeing the setting for the Sticky Edges in Settings -> Displays, but I can't find that option in Gnome. Where can I turn on/off Sticky Edges in Gnome?

Comment: Try fiddling with some options in the Compiz Config Settings Manager from the package `compizconfig-settings-manager`.

Comment: on a dual screen setup, if you have the dock on the right screen with 'auto-hide' it can act like a sticky edge.  just move the dock to the left most screen - or disable autohide

Answer (score 12):

Sorry for the late answer, but better late than never?

The setting you are looking for can be done graphically in `dconf-editor`, navigating to `/org/gnome/shell/overrides` and toggling the value `edge-tiling`, as appears below:

[image: dconf-editor]

---

To do this using a CLI, enter the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides edge-tiling false
```

to turn off the tiling at the edge of the screen, or

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides edge-tiling true
```

to set it back on.

Comment: No issue with the late answer :-) however, I don't have the /org folder. :(

Comment: @sedulam Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: @sedulam I checked 14.04, 16.04 and 17.10 - the org folder is present in all of these...

Comment: I installed the 16.04.3 with Gnome, could that be it? These are the folders I have: bin/    etc/             lib/         mnt/   run/   sys/  
boot/   home/            lib64/       opt/   sbin/  tmp/  
cdrom/  lost+found/  proc/  snap/  usr/
dev/    media/       root/  srv/   var/

Comment: @sedulam Ah - I have confused you!  Start the program `dconf-editor` -> the paths for the settings are inside that program (not directories on your disk)

Comment: Got it now, unfortunately, regardless of the value, I still keep having sticky edges (I want to turn it off) :( thanks anyway though!

Comment: @sedulam I'll be offline for a bit here - there has been some confusion in the past about what "Sticky Edges" does - what behaviour are you trying to stop?

Comment: When I drag a window to a corner of one of my screens, the window jumps a bit and sticks to the edges. Also, when trying to remove the window from the border, the movement is not smooth, because it suddenly jumps after dragging it a bit, but it doesn't move before the jump.

Comment: I disabled this and still had the issue. I realized that it was the dock on my primary display (my top display) that was causing the mouse to 'stick' at the boundary. Moving the dock to the left side solved the issue.

Comment: I managed to resolve it by rearranging displays position. Seems one was slightly too high in the GUI. Once I rearranged this it worked. 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: For me it was the "Workspaces to dock" extension causing the extra stickiness. Changing this dock location to bottom using Gnome-Tweaks fixed it. You can also just disable it.

Comment: unfortunately when I drag my mouse pointer across monitor boundaries, it still sticks as it crosses the boundary which is super annoying :(