# Can I turn off window snapping in GNOME 3?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, window-manager, window-management

I want to avoid my windows snapping to the edge of my screen when resizing and moving, but it doesn't seem to work.

I am running GNOME 3.28.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. I see no options for snapping when I go through the native Settings app, I have `gnome-tweaks` in which I see no options for snapping, and I have Compiz config which **does** have options for snapping, but unchecking it has no effect. Which has me wondering if Compiz config is outdated for GNOME 3 or something? My `apt` says it's the latest version, `1:0.9.13.1+18.04.20180302-0ubuntu1`.

So, can I turn off window snapping in some alternative "hacky" way?

#### Edit

The suggested duplicate thread didn't solve it for me. I turned off the setting in Dconf editor as per the accepted answer, but they still snap. It seems quite inconsistent, and i can't figure out if it depends on the type of application or size of the window or what, however the title bar on top always snaps, whereas sides sometimes don't.

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://askubuntu.com/questions/907797/how-to-turn-off-sticky-edges-in-ubuntu-gnome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(18.04) How to disable the window resizing when accidentally touching one of the screen edges?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029168/18-04-how-to-disable-the-window-resizing-when-accidentally-touching-one-of-the)

Comment: Which one did you turn off using dconf editor?

Comment: If you mean the commands from your other accepted answer, i ran both. I even tried it as `sudo` now, just in case, it still snaps. But for example the terminal window snaps differently than Firefox. If i don't let the edge of terminal quite touch the edge of the screen, it will allow me to leave it close to it. Once they touch, i just have to drag away far to unsnap it. But for Firefox i can never leave it close; if i leave it close and let my mouse go, it adjusts the position and snaps it to the edge.

Comment: "I even tried it as sudo" is not a good idea. Running things with *sudo* could alter permissions of files/folders in your home directory thereby making them inaccessible to you as a normal user.

Answer (score 5):

You have probably found the solution by now, but just in case you have not yet found it or some one else is interested. The **gnome-tweaks** option you are looking for is called '**Edge Tiling**' located in the **Windows** section.

Comment: You're probably talking about newer release(s) of Ubuntu, but the question was originally asked for Ubuntu 18.04 which *does not* have this specific option.

Comment: Oh! Thank you. @I_Ranger

Answer (score 0):

In **K**Ubuntu v20.04 i do:

Disable:

[x] Screen Edges > Maximize dragged on top edge

A console solution (not tested by me): https://askubuntu.com/a/1029186/1017209

Comment: Kubuntu does not use the Gnome 3 desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was deselecting

\CompizConfig Settings
\Window Management
\grid

Works great!  Now windows go where I want them and when I want them to be there :)

Comment: What desktop environment do you use CompizConfig with? Gnome 3? Is it still relevant / supported?

Comment: Running Linux Mint 19.3 with Mate as the desktop manager

Comment: looks like i have gnome 3.28

Comment: MATE is not Gnome 3...