# 18.04 problem moving mouse cursor between monitors

Tags: 18.04, gnome, multiple-monitors, mouse

After getting annoyed by it for the seemingly hundredth time, I tried to turn off Sticky Edges today. I couldn't!

Sticky edges, as I'm defining it: when moving the mouse cursor between monitors, it is 'stuck' on the edge until you've moved the mouse enough to push through the barrier. AFAIK, this was a feature you could turn off in Unity, but not in Gnome?

(To get across I have to move the mouse almost as though there were another monitor to cross, to get to the other one.)

(edit to add: this only is an issue in one direction, from the external monitor to the primary (laptop) one. Going from primary to external has no problem.)

Some extensive googling has only led me to these two posts, and neither solve the issue.

[This one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907797/how-to-turn-off-sticky-edges-in-ubuntu-gnome) starts talking more about edge-tiling (which is when the window you're dragging snaps to full-screen or half-screen depending on which monitor edge you drag to, top or sides respectively)

[And this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1726464) has it as a bug report that seems unfixed?

I've tried all the variations that these posts suggest,

- Moving the dock from both displays to one,
- Changing the dock to the bottom (so that it ostensibly shouldn't interrupt the mouse,
- turning off the auto-hide of the dock (assuming the sticky edge was connected to the auto-hide behavior)

I've also tried looking in dconf for something to disable.

So far, nothing. Has anyone else solved this on their own?

Comment: have you changed any settings? i have few times used dual monitors.. out of the box in my 18.04 i didn't face this..

Comment: Not that I can think of. Or lots of settings away from factory(or out of the box), if you include the Gnome Extensions.

Comment: i tried it to reproduce.. but cant.. ofcourse i dont have gnome shell extensions installed and enabled other than `dash to panel` and `user themes` and the first thing i do after a fresh install 0f 18.04 is to remove pre-enabled 2 extensions `ubuntu-dock` and other `some indicator`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some recent updates, the problem is now minimal. There is a slight bump shifting the mouse cursor between screens, but it's minimal and no longer a process of moving the mouse an extreme amount just to cross the threshold. That bump now feels like a usability feature rather than a bug! I'm assuming there was something that got affected in an update and fixed in a later update!

Although I cannot determine what it was that caused the error or what was done to fix it, the age old advice remains true with any problem: have you tried updating first?