# How to use menu (Ubuntu dock) on right screen in 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I am using two screens. The menu (Ubuntu dock) is shown at the left screen. I would like to have it on the right screen:

[image]

Changing the right monitor as primary screen does not help. Only the top bar is now shown at the right monitor and on the left monitor is a gap between the menu at the top.

Is it not possible to have the menu at the right in 18.04?

Answer (score 2):

One has to set the right screen as primary screen:

[image]

The only reason why I didn't see the menu on the right screen immediately, is because one needs to restart the PC or to log off & log in again. Now it works:

[image]

Comment: Just a pointer, it seems you set the right monitor as the primary monitor to have the dock there. But you can also have the dock any any particular monitor without changing the primary monitor, refer to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080228/how-do-i-get-the-sidebar-ubuntu-dock-off-the-secondary-monitor

Answer (score 1):

If you want the dock on every monitor you can do the following.

Install dconf editor with `sudo apt install dconf-editor`

Then open it, search for "multi-monitor" and toggle the first result on.