# Want to change the direction that my mouse exits the screen on dual monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, mouse, cursor

I am currently running Ubuntu 18.04 on a dual monitor system. My problem is that I just changed my secondary monitor and now my mouse exits the main screen and goes to the secondary screen in the opposite direction it did before I changed monitors.

Before my primary monitor was in front of me and the secondary monitor was to my right, I was able to move my cursor off the right hand side of the main screen to the left hand side of the secondary screen (which is what I wanted to do because it gives me better work flow). Now after changing monitors my mouse exits from the left side of the main screen and enters on the right side of the secondary screen (did not change position of the main and secondary screens).

The only thing that has really changed as far as the screens go is that the secondary screen is now a larger display. Even tried changing the cabling because one monitor is VGA and the other is DVI, but it did not change the mouse direction on exit. I did not see any way to change the mouse movement in either the system settings or the gnome tweak tool.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Change the relative locations of the two monitors

Open **Settings > Devices > Displays** and use your mouse to move the second monitor where you want it:

[image]

Finally click the green <kbd>Apply</kbd> on the top right edge of the window. If the two displays are of different sizes, you can also align the smaller display to the middle (as I have) or with the top or the bottom of the bigger display. If everything looks okay, click on "Keep Change" or else "Revert Settings" as prompted.

Once you move the second monitor to the left of the first monitor as shown above, you may want to move the The dock and the top bar to the left most screen as well. You can do this by making the screen 2 the primary display, as shown in the figure above.

If you want the dock to appear on both the screens go to appearances tab on the left panel of the settings window and change it there as shown in [the answer by Dan Dascalescu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1238966/480481).

Hope this helps

Comment: Does this also help to have the taskbar on my left screen? (The monitors are locked and I cannot move them :) )

Comment: @nooshinha I have added how to move the dock (taskbar) to the left window in my answer.