# Dock shows in both displays can't change the settings. ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-dock

I installed ubuntu 20.04 and I have a separate display. in the setting, there is an option that add a dock to both displays. I just tried it and it worked, now I can't undo this. when I select the option to the built-in display it won't work and automatically change back to the all-displays option.

[image]

any suggestions