# Having the dock on different sides of two monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, dock

Ubuntu beginner here. I'd like to have the dock on the left side of my left monitor and on the right side of my right monitor, but the settings force me to keep the dock on the same side (that is, left side on left monitor and left side on right monitor). Is there any solution to this? I'm on version 21.04 if it is relevant.

edit: To clarify, I want the dock on both my monitors. The problem is that Ubuntu doesn't seem to allow me to keep the dock on different sides of my monitors, only on the left, bottom or right of both, but no combinations.

[Dock settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9R78S.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the Ubuntu Dock off the secondary monitor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080228/how-do-i-get-the-ubuntu-dock-off-the-secondary-monitor)